# SObjectType.newSobject(null, true) doesn't populate default values if called in vf action method, any tips?

Tags: apex, platform-bug, describefieldresult, default-value, dynamic-apex

I'm trying to create an sObject instance using following code:

```
Schema.SObjectType targetType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName);
sObject sObj = targetType.newSObject(null, true);
```

This works great in anonymous apex and test methods. But when I plugged it all into a visualforce page things started misbehaving. Specifically the defaults worked for the first row of records, but any rows created via `<apex:commandLink action="{!addMore}">` don't respect the defaults that work fine in the constructor. For example note the first row has a default date and type, but the next row just has nulls.

[image]

I've tried every permutation of wiring this all together, but none have worked so far ...

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="MyListController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageMessages id="msgs" />
        <apex:dataTable id="tbRelatedList"  value="{!sObjRelatedRecords}" var="sObjRel">
            <apex:facet name="footer">
                <apex:outputPanel >
                    <apex:commandlink action="{!addMore}" rerender="msgs,{!$Component.tbRelatedList}">
                        Add
                    </apex:commandlink>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:facet>
            <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                <apex:inputField required="false" value="{!sObjRel['Name']}" />
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Date">
                <apex:inputField required="false" value="{!sObjRel['Date__c']}" />
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Type">
                <apex:inputField required="false" value="{!sObjRel['Type__c']}" />
            </apex:column>
        </apex:dataTable>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**APEX Class:**

```
public with sharing class MyListController() {
    public MyListController() {
        sObjectName         = 'MyCustomObj__c';
        sObjRelatedRecords  = new list<sObject>();
        this.addMore();
    }

    public string           sObjectName         { get;set; }
    public list<sObject>    sObjRelatedRecords  { get;set; }

    public void addMore() {
        try {
            Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd  = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
            Schema.SObjectType targetType       = gd.get(sObjectName);
            sObject sObjR                       = targetType.newSObject(null, true);

            sObjRelatedRecords.add( sObjR );
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ApexPages.addMessages( ex )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `inserting` the record into the database set the default values?

Comment: Is this in a class? If so, what's the API version? I tried this in my org and it did work as expected.

Comment: Executing the same code (above) in Execute Anonymous does save record with default values populated. And the API version of `APEX class` & `VF page` is `44.0`. The full code involves a List of sObject that are binded on VF page, and user can click Add button to add more records to the list. The above code is of the `add` button call, so everytime I click Add More to add another record to the list I only get an sObject instance with No Default values.

Comment: I have updated my question with Full Code including VF & APEX code. API version of both is `44.0`. The behavior I'm receiving is, the `addMore()` done in constructor is populating all Default field values for the first record, but as I add new record to list using "Add" button in VF, the subsequent records all have No Default values in any field (from first record in the list).

Comment: So, I was able to replicate the issue. Seems pretty odd, that if you run the code from a Test Class, it works as expected. The issue seems to be ONLY happening on DATE fields when the method is called from VF page. E.g., if I have another field which is defaulted, it is rendered fine on VF page, it's just the DATE field that is having issue. Still trying to see if there's a fix for this or why is this happening.

Comment: Actually, in my case, Picklist field also mis-behaving. But good thing is, I'm able to read picklist via `getDefaultValue()` Field Describe method. but `date` field do not return any value for defaultFieldvalue() methods either.

Comment: I actually had a picklist field in addition to date in my test, and it was working fine. You may also like to reach out to SF Support on this.

Comment: I just tried it again. For me, if I click on "Add" link to add more sObject records, the newly added record do not have any default value unless I use following piece of code: `sObjRelatedRecords.put('Type__c', Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('MyCustomObject__c').getDescribe().fields.getMap().get('Type__c').getDescribe().getDefaultValue());` I need to repeat this for any field I expect to hold a default value. Except Date fields, which always return `null` default as value :(

Comment: here is how it looks like in VF rendered output: [VF output screenshot](https://www.screencast.com/t/BrqpdOjAo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, definitely a bug, fortunately easy work around. Since the default values seem to be completely ignored in the context of a visualforce postback, but work fine in the constructor we can work around this by creating a base record template in the constructor and cloning that in the add more methods.

#### Controller

```
public with sharing class SFS_238148_3 {

    public String sObjectName { get; set; }
    public SObject[] sObjList { get; set; }

    private SObject baseRec;

    public SFS_238148_3() {
        sObjectName = 'Test__c';
        sObjList = new SObject[0];
        // works as expected in the constructor
        baseRec = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjectName).newSObject(null, true);
        addMore();
    }

    public void addMore() {
        // re-use the object created in the constructor
        // where we know the default values are getting populated
        sObjList.add(baseRec.clone(false));
    }
}
```

#### VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="SFS_238148_3">
<apex:form>
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
        <apex:commandButton value="Add More" action="{!addMore}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!sobjList}" var="sObj">
        <apex:column headerValue="Name">
            <apex:inputField value="{!sObj['Name']}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Date">
            <apex:inputField value="{!sObj['Date__c']}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Picklist">
            <apex:inputField value="{!sObj['Picklist__c']}"/>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: gr8 workaround, didn't thought of it. It worked like a charm!

Comment: Very well thought!

Answer (score 0):

### First Pass

Default values for dates and picklists should work with the `newSobject` method. At least they do for. See below for he code I used to try and reproduce your issue. Got the excepted behavior in anonymous apex, test code, and visualforce controllers, with both direct references to the sObjectType and dynamic ones, and using direct field references and dynamic field references in the vf page. For good measure I also added a record type as well and confirmed no further issues.

[image: my vf page output]

You might try out my code below and see if it works for you. If it doesn't definitely file a case with support with a simplified test case. If it does there must be something special with your visualforce page, even though it looks totally fine to me. In that case, I'd suggest re-purposing my code that's working and making small piecemeal changes into your desired layout checking after each change to see if things stop working.

#### Custom Object

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fields>
        <fullName>Date__c</fullName>
        <defaultValue>TODAY()</defaultValue>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>Date</label>
        <required>false</required>
        <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
        <type>Date</type>
    </fields>
    <fields>
        <fullName>Picklist__c</fullName>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>Picklist</label>
        <required>false</required>
        <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
        <type>Picklist</type>
        <valueSet>
            <restricted>true</restricted>
            <valueSetDefinition>
                <sorted>false</sorted>
                <value>
                    <fullName>Default</fullName>
                    <default>true</default>
                    <label>Default</label>
                </value>
                <value>
                    <fullName>Not</fullName>
                    <default>false</default>
                    <label>Not</label>
                </value>
            </valueSetDefinition>
        </valueSet>
    </fields>
</CustomObject>
```

#### Controller

```
public with sharing class SFS_238148 {

    public Test__c rec1 { get; set; }
    public Test__c rec2 { get; set; }
    public SObject rec3 { get; set; }
    public SObject rec4 { get; set; }

    public SFS_238148() {
        // test with direct sobject type reference
        rec1 = (Test__c) Test__c.sobjectType.newSObject(null, true);
        System.debug(rec1.Date__c);   
        System.debug(rec1.Picklist__c);
        // test with dynamic sobject type reference 
        rec2 = (Test__c) Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Test__c').newSobject(null, true);
        System.debug(rec2.Date__c);   
        System.debug(rec2.Picklist__c);
        rec3 = Test__c.sobjectType.newSObject(null, true);
        System.debug(rec3.get('Date__c'));
        System.debug(rec3.get('Picklist__c'));
        rec4 = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Test__c').newSobject(null, true);
        System.debug(rec4.get('Date__c'));
        System.debug(rec4.get('Picklist__c'));
    }
}
```

#### Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page controller="SFS_238148">
<apex:form >
    <h1>Test__c rec1 = (Test__c) Test__c.sobjectType.newSObject(null, true);</h1><br/>
    Direct Date: <apex:inputField value="{!rec1.Date__c}"/><br/>
    Direct Picklist: <apex:inputField value="{!rec1.Picklist__c}"/><br/>
    Dynamic Date: <apex:inputField value="{!rec1['Date__c']}"/><br/>
    Dynamic Picklist: <apex:inputField value="{!rec1['Picklist__c']}"/><br/><br/>
    <h1>Test__c rec2 = (Test__c) Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Test__c').newSobject(null, true);</h1><br/>
    Direct Date: <apex:inputField value="{!rec2.Date__c}"/><br/>
    Direct Picklist: <apex:inputField value="{!rec2.Picklist__c}"/><br/>
    Dynamic Date: <apex:inputField value="{!rec2['Date__c']}"/><br/>
    Dynamic Picklist: <apex:inputField value="{!rec2['Picklist__c']}"/><br/><br/>
    <h1>SObject rec3 = Test__c.sobjectType.newSObject(null, true);</h1><br/>
    Dynamic Date: <apex:inputField value="{!rec3['Date__c']}"/><br/>
    Dynamic Picklist: <apex:inputField value="{!rec3['Picklist__c']}"/><br/><br/>
    <h1>SObject rec4 = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Test__c').newSobject(null, true);</h1><br/>
    Dynamic Date: <apex:inputField value="{!rec4['Date__c']}"/><br/>
    Dynamic Picklist: <apex:inputField value="{!rec4['Picklist__c']}"/><br/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

#### Test Class

```
@isTest
private class SFS_238148_Test {

    @isTest
    private static void checkDefaultValues() {
        SFS_238148 controller = new SFS_238148();
        System.assertEquals(Date.today(), controller.rec1.Date__c);
        System.assertEquals('Default', controller.rec1.Picklist__c);
        System.assertEquals(Date.today(), controller.rec2.Date__c);
        System.assertEquals('Default', controller.rec2.Picklist__c);
        System.assertEquals(Date.today(), controller.rec3.get('Date__c'));
        System.assertEquals('Default', controller.rec3.get('Picklist__c'));
        System.assertEquals(Date.today(), controller.rec4.get('Date__c'));
        System.assertEquals('Default', controller.rec4.get('Picklist__c'));
    }
}
```

### Second Pass

Well now I'm running into the same issues. Record instantiated as the result of a vf button click seem to skip the initialization which definitely feels like a bug.

### Discussion

Things work great when the page loads and the constructor calls the addMore() method, regardless of your using a direct SObjectType or GlobalDescribe, or the generic SObject or specific Test__c, but if the same method is called from a VF button none of the defaults are applied in any scneario

#### Page Load

All defaults are as expected
[[image: defaults on load]]

But *NONE* of the defaults are populated when 'Add More' button clicked

[image]

### Controller

```
public with sharing class SFS_238148_2 {

    public Test__c[] typedList { get; set; }
    public SObject[] sObjList { get; set; }

    public SFS_238148_2() {
        typedList = new Test__c[0];
        sObjList = new SObject[0];
        this.addMore();
    }

    public void addMore() {
        typedList.add(newRecDirect());
        typedList.add(newRecIndirect());
        sObjList.add(newSObjDirect());
        sObjList.add(newSObjIndirect());
    }

    public Test__c newRecDirect() {
        Test__c rec = (Test__c) Test__c.sobjectType.newSObject(null, true);
        rec.Name = '(Test__c) Test__c.sobjectType.newSObject(null, true);';
        return rec;
    }

    public Test__c newRecIndirect() {
        Test__c rec = (Test__c) Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Test__c').newSobject(null, true);
        rec.Name = '(Test__c) Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(\'Test__c\').newSobject(null, true);';
        return rec;
    }

    public SObject newSObjDirect() {
        SObject rec = Test__c.sobjectType.newSObject(null, true);
        rec.put('Name', 'Test__c.sobjectType.newSObject(null, true);');
        return rec;
    }

    public SObject newSObjIndirect() {
        SObject rec = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Test__c').newSobject(null, true);
        rec.put('Name', 'Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(\'Test__c\').newSobject(null, true);');
        return rec;
    }
}
```

### Test Class

*These all pass*

```
@isTest
private class SFS_238148_2_Test {

    @isTest
    private static void SFS_238148_2() {
        SFS_238148_2 controller = new SFS_238148_2();
        checkIt(controller);
        controller.addMore();
        checkIt(controller);
    }

    private static void checkIt(SFS_238148_2 controller) {
        for (Test__c rec : controller.typedList) {
            System.assertEquals(Date.today(), rec.Date__c);
            System.assertEquals('Default', rec.Picklist__c);
        }
        for (SObject rec : controller.sobjList) {
            System.assertEquals(Date.today(), rec.get('Date__c'));
            System.assertEquals('Default', rec.get('Picklist__c'));   
        }
    }
}
```

### Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page controller="SFS_238148_2">
<apex:form>
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
        <apex:commandButton value="Add More" action="{!addMore}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <apex:pageBlockTable title="Typed List - Direct Constructor" value="{!typedList}" var="rec">
        <apex:column headerValue="Init Method" value="{!rec.Name}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="rec.Date__c">
            <apex:inputField value="{!rec.Date__c}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="rec.Picklist__c">
            <apex:inputField value="{!rec.Picklist__c}"/>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    <apex:pageBlockTable title="Typed List - Dynamic Constructor" value="{!typedList}" var="rec">
        <apex:column headerValue="Init Method" value="{!rec.Name}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="rec['Date__c']">
            <apex:inputField value="{!rec['Date__c']}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="rec['Picklist__c']">
            <apex:inputField value="{!rec['Picklist__c']}"/>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    <apex:pageBlockTable title="Generic List - Dynamic Constructor" value="{!sObjList}" var="sObj">
        <apex:column headerValue="Init Method">
            <apex:outputField value="{!sObj['Name']}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="sObj['Date__c']">
            <apex:inputField value="{!sObj['Date__c']}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="sObj['Picklist__c']">
            <apex:inputField value="{!sObj['Picklist__c']}"/>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: thanks for checking on this. But single instance variable is working good with me as well, it is when you have a List of sObjects and you try to Add more items to it, the added items won't have default values. Try my code provided in question above and if possibel confirm if you find issue or not. In short I think `newSObject()` call in `constructor` works fine, but not when it is in called from a button on VF.

Comment: interesting, giving a go at reproducing things in a list and via visualforce button

Comment: yep, seeing the same thing, same method produces different results depending on whether it's called from a vf page button or not (same method works fine in test methods.

Comment: i think i got a good workaround for you though

Comment: sure any workaround that can take me past this is appreciated :-) ... though, can you suggest if there is any way to make this issue reach out to Salesforce for Known Issue?

Comment: workaround coming shortly

Comment: @VarunC if you want to be a good citizen, create a very basic example case, just one field, and show how the same method behaves differently in a vf constructor than in an vf action button. As long as it's super simple to understand it might not be too difficult to push it through to tier 3 where there are actually people who care about fixing bugs. ... it's a noble effort, but honestly salesforce support is designed to not find bugs IMHO

Comment: Yes certainly, will try, but so far everytime I had tried raising a support request that concerns VF or APEX, the case was simply closed without even getting any traction citing we need premier support for Developer issues :-)

Comment: ask around and see if you know someone who has premier support and can log it for you, or just keep immediately pushing back that "I'm not asking for developer support, I've got a bug you should be aware of, do you not want bug reports?"

Comment: or even "I've already got a work around, but clearly there is a bug here, can you please submit to tier 3 so they can decide whether this warrants a known issue"

Comment: thx Ralph will try. If you don't mind, using similar dynamic code I'm getting into another issue with sObjects - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/238276/dynamic-sobject-lookup-field-throws-sobject-row-does-not-allow-errors-if-looku ... can you quickly take a look at this, if possible. your workaround seems to hold good for me in this query :)