# Dynamic sObject Lookup field throws "SObject row does not allow errors" if lookup is entered record name that do not exist in org

Tags: apex, error, inputfield, bug, dynamic-apex

Feels like I'm not having a good day at all with platform :-) ... another day and another issue with platform dynamic sObjects :(

So I'm trying to create an sObject record dynamically from a VF page. In that there is a Lookup field to be included in the form dynamically. Now, usually lookup field value can be selected by using the lookup button to search and select a specific record OR by simply typing the name of the record. Platform selects a valid record or alert user that record entered by name do not exist or not found.

So now I'm seeing with dynamic sObjects it is thrown an untrappable error:

> SObject row does not allow errors

To test it, simply copy my code below and in the Account Lookup field enter a value `12345xyz` (or simply a value that you're sure do not exist in your org as an `Account`).
And press `Save` button, you get this error, and everything on the form is lost even if you have placed `try/catch` in your code.

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="MyTestDynamicSObject">
    <apex:form id="theForm">
        <apex:pageBlock mode="edit">
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!saveRecord}" value="Save" reRender="theForm" status="loading" />
                <apex:actionStatus id="status" startText="(loading...)"></apex:actionStatus>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:inputField value="{!sObjRecord['LastName']}" required="false" /><br />
                <apex:inputField value="{!sObjRecord['AccountId']}" required="false" /><br /><br />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**APEX Class:**

```
public class MyTestDynamicSObject {
    public MyTestDynamicSObject() {
        sObjRecord      = (sObject) Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Contact').newSObject(null, true);
        sObjRecord.put('LastName', 'Test name');
    }

    public  sObject     sObjRecord  { get;set; }

    public void saveRecord() {
        try {
            insert sObjRecord;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so what's the point of using the generic sobject in this case, why not just have it be a contact?

Comment: I only simplified my objective and this query with `sample` reproducible code. My code is lot complex than this, it has to support `any` `sObject` in the org and form is generated dynamically with dynamic number of fields.

Comment: got an answer for you, but honestly, you might be better off focusing on a DSL that generates the forms you want for each dynamic object. To see a great implementation of this check out passage tech's rollup helper package. It's not a UI, but a trigger, but they dynamically generate a trigger specific to an object on demand.

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that for generic SObjects, if you submit a lookup without first clicking the lookup icon, and the string doesn't match a parent object you'll get the apparently uncatchable "SObject row does not allow errors"

Option 1 - Add some instructions that tell the user to click the magnifying glass before clicking save and ensure they've found a particular contact.

Option 2 - Ditch the generic version and just create a individual pages for each object. I.e. have a setup page where you define the object and the fields, then you click a button and build and deploy a visualforce page that uses concrete sobjects instead of generics.

Option 3 - Just build a page for every permutation of objects since if it's a concrete sobject you'll get a nice "Account Name: No Matches found" error and the field will get highlighted.

Option 4 - Add your own error handling
- update the save button to run some javascript that first querieis to see if the account name is valid, and if it isn't display a useful error message before you get to the uncatchable error.

Comment: I've found following [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000Sz5RAAS) for this issue. Sadly, it is not going to be fixed. But I am able to get past the error if I disable loadDefaults.